# How to stop server side validation (validating malicious input) in aspx on particular button postback?

Tags: asp.net, validation

In the web form we have save button and cancel button, In save i want the validation to happen in server side (default server side validation, checking for malicious input), but i want to stop this validation from happening for cancel button. (Cancel button simply do a postback to the server page1 and redirects it to page2)

I tried to get the posted control id in the page load event, through Request.Params[""], (when I accessed the property, validation exception occurred, because I sent malicious input like <"script">). My idea was that if I am able to get posted control button id (like cancel), then we can stop validation manually. I tried to get posted control id through Request.Unvalidated (I searched in Google, but not able to find any solution to get posted control Id). Even I get posted control Id somehow, I don't know how to stop the validation. So my question is how to stop aspx validation for certain controls postback?

Comment: maybe clear all fields using JavaScript on click of `Cancel` before the form is posted to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JavaScript to clear all fields on click of `Cancel` before the form is posted to the server. You can use the following JS to find all fields and clear them.

```
var clearFields = function() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1) {
    inputs[i].value = '';
  }
};
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rvwd0jqv/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can set `CausesValidation` to `false` for the Cancel button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" ... />
```

If the Cancel button simply redirects to another page, you could avoid the postback and redirect from the client code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" OnClientClick="window.location.href='page2.aspx'; return false;" ... />
```

Comment: I already set CausesVaidation=false, but the problem is if I type some malicious text in the textbox and click on cancel, I will receive potentially dangerous input exception occurred exception, because of the server side validation. However I want this exception to occur if I click Save button, but if I click cancel button I don't want this excepetion to occur. If I set ValidateOnPostback=false in the page, then I can stop this from happening completely, but I want this exception to occur when clicking on save, and not to happen when clicking on cancel

Comment: Can you show us (in the question) what you do in the Cancel button event handler? Do you need that button to cause a postback?

Comment: I updated the question, I will say it here also, (Cancel button simply do a postback to the server page1 and redirects it to page2). Now Page 1 has some text box, a save & cancel button. If I type some thing like html tag in the text box and if I click on cancel button, I receive potentially dangerous input exception. While clicking on Save button I do validation on client side using regular expression, but i can't do the same for cancel, because cancel button only need to do is a redirect.